# finding out if the characters of a string exist in another string with the same order or not using regex in java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

i want to write a program in java using REGEX that gets 2 strings from the input ( the first one is shorter than the second one ) and then if the characters of the first string was inside the second string with the same order but they do not need to be next to each other ( it is ***not*** substring ) it outputs "true" and if not it outputs "false" here's an example:

example1:

input:

phantom

p***ph***vnb***a***jknzxcvb***n***a***to***popoi***m***

output:

true

in the above example  it is obvious we can see the word "phantom" in the second string (the characters are in the same order)

example2:

input:

apple

fg***a***yiy***p***vbn***l***tsrgt***e***

output:

false

as you can see apple dos not exists in the second string with the conditions i have earlier mentioned so it outputs false

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String word1 = input.next();

        String word2 = input.next();

        String pattern = "";

        int n = word1.length();

        char[] word1CharArr = word1.toCharArray();

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {

            pattern += "[:alnum:]" +word1CharArr[i]+"[:alnum:]";

           // pattern += ".*\\b|\\B" +word1CharArr[i]+"\\b|\\B";
        }

        pattern = "^" + pattern + "$";

       // pattern = "(?s)" + pattern + ".*";

       // System.out.println(pattern);

       System.out.println(word2.matches(pattern));
    }
}
```

here is what i did . i broke my first string to its characters and want to use REGEX before and after each character to determine the pattern. I have searched much about REGEX and how to use it but still i have problem here. the part i have commented comes out from one of my searches but it did not work
I emphasize that i want to solve it with REGEX not any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[:alnum:]` isn't a thing. Even if it is, that would match exactly *one* character, not 'any number, from 0 to infinitely many of them'.

You just want `phantom` with `.*` in the middle: `^.*p.*h.*a.*n.*t.*o.*m.*$' is all you need. After all,` phantom` 'fits', and so does paahaanaataaoaamaa -

```
String pattern = word1.chars()
  .mapToObj(c -> ".*" + (char) c)
  .collect(Collectors.joining()) + ".*";
```

should get the job done.

Comment: i do not get the code (line 2 and 3 ) can you explain it please

Comment: [Lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: It's just turning `phantom` into `.*p.*h.*a.*n.*t.*o.*m.*` - you don't need the ^ and $ (`.matches` already matches against the entire string), you can use a for loop if you prefer.